# Align centered reCaptha element in div

Tags: java, html, css, recaptcha

I'm using the reCaptha in my website, I have this code, in Java:

```
<div id="reCAPTCHA"><c:out value="${requestScope.reCapchaChallenge}" escapeXml="false" /></div>
```

The problem is, the reCaptcha object is not centered within the div ID=reCAPTCHA, it is left-aligned.

What fix it?

Comment: Can you provide the html code that the c:out gives you? The html inside the reCAPTCHA div that will be shown for the user.

Comment: I returned it is already done, I have no control over the html, is provided by reCAPTCHA.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one approach. I believe `reCaptcha` has a set width. To find it's width I would just use Chrome Inspector, Firebug, etc. Then use CSS like so:

Example with image as placeholder for reCaptcha, http://jsfiddle.net/TK87b/

*CSS*

```css
#reCAPTCHA {
     width: 300px; /* whatever the width of reCaptcha is */
     margin: 0 auto;
}
```

*HTML*

```html
<div id="reCAPTCHA">
     <!-- your reCaptcha code -->
</div>
```

Comment: I had done it and succeeded. I forgot to come here warn. Yes it works, but the width is 310. Tks anyway man.